# Issues Installing Oracle Xe 10g on CentOs 4.6

Tags: linux, centos, installation, oracle10g

Help!

Trying to re-install Oracle XE 10g on my CentOS 4.6 Machine from RPM and cannot complete the installation, prompting the following error:

```
error: unpacking of archive failed: cpio: lstat failed - Input/output error
```

I have searched for options, looking at installation instructions, and possible mistakes, going as far as running a LiveCD to run fsck to check for corruptions but no dice.

If anyone has any input. I would deeply appreciate it [More Info Below]

```
 [root@myserver]# rpm -ivh oracle-xe-univ-10.2.0.1-1.0.i386.rpm --force
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
       1:oracle-xe-univ         
warning: /etc/init.d/oracle-xe saved as /etc/init.d/oracle-xe.rpmorig
warning: /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/config/scripts/postDBCreation.sql saved as /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/config/scripts/postDBCreation.sql.rpmorig
    warning: /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/network/admin/listener.ora saved as /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/network/admin/listener.ora.rpmorig
    ########################################### [100%]
    error: unpacking of archive failed: cpio: lstat failed - Input/output error
```

Comment: After much searching I ended up deleting force deleting the folders in /etc/init.d/oracle-xe folder and re-installing from a new oracle version. Thanks for the input

Comment: Rather than mark the question title [Solved] post an answer which details how you solved the issue then accept it in a couple of days. This shows somebody else with the same problem what the solution is and with the accepted answer it shows Server Fault users that there's no need to read the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following ChrisF's advice I will answer my own question with the steps I followed to solve the issue I was having:

Step 1.

With an Ubuntu 10.04 loaded to a pendrive, I booted into the server, and proceeded to rebuild the journaled ext3 drive and then run a fsck on that partition.

Step 2.

I Downloaded Oracle XE 10g Universal from Oracle website.

Step 3. 
Deleted previous install files with 
    $rm -rF /etc/init.d/oracle-xe

Step 4.

Re-install

Answer (score 0):

Try re downloading it.  It might simply have been a corrupt or incomplete download.

Comment: I did got a second version from another source, and then proceeded to download from Oracle the RPM but still get the same message